# delete margin each 3 div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have this code:

```
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
```

and css:

```
.post {position:relative;float:left;margin-right:10px;}
```

I need that each 3 div.post, the third have margin-right:0px;

Comment: Please provide your attempted code and tell us what went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.post:nth-child(4n)
{
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Please note the [browser compatibility of CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).

Comment: But, this put margin-right:0px in second div

Comment: works with (4n), change answer and i'll vote you

Comment: odd...(3n) or (3n+0) should work for every 3 divs.

Comment: @showdev A conscientious developer could [use Modernizr to detect `last-child` support](http://modernizr.com/download/#-shiv-cssclasses-teststyles-css_lastchild-load) and then conditionally use JavaScript or jQuery to add classes.

Comment: this work with internet explorer?

Comment: @vektor Natively, only IE9+. See Blazemonger's comment for additional support.

Comment: 9+, as @showdev mentioned

Comment: 9.0.8112.16421 64bit and don't work

Comment: this css works perfect, how can i put in jquery for iexplorer and older browsers? some idea?

Answer (score 2):

For modern browsers, pure CSS `nth-child` selectors will be sufficient:

```
.post:nth-child(3n) { /* not zero-based */
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/EQacc/

If there are other sibling elements before the first `div.post`, you'll want to use `nth-of-type` instead:

```
.post:nth-of-type(3n) {
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4vnjt/

For older browsers (including IE8 and before), some JavaScript will be necessary. I would use jQuery to add a class to every third item, and add that class to my CSS:

```
.post.thirdchild, .post:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.post:nth-of-type(3n)').addClass('thirdchild');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Tf9ky/

Why include both? Well, some users may have JavaScript turned off.

---

In fact, if you're concerned about IE<8, the ideal solution might be to make 0px the default margin, so that there's no chance the posts will overflow their container:

```
.post {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.post.notthirdchild,
.post:nth-child(3n+1), 
.post:nth-child(3n+2) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.post:nth-child(3n+1),.post:nth-child(3n+2').addClass('notthirdchild');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nBLxc/

Comment: this works, but put margin-right:0px in second div, not third

Comment: sorry, in the first. why?¿?

Comment: Shouldn't be: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/EQacc/ -- perhaps you have other sibiling elements before the first `div.post`? Updated answer.

Comment: with that code, again put margin-right:0px in second div. i don't understand why

Comment: You'll have to share a larger sample of your HTML, then. I'm sure there are other elements affecting the CSS.

Comment: maybe is because i'm work on wordpress? post of wordpress

Comment: this work perfect: .post:nth-child(4n) {margin-right:0px !important;}
How can i do for internet explorer and old browsers?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
$('.post').each(function(){
    i++;
    if(i%3==0){
        $(this).css('margin-right', '0');
    }
});
```

Comment: really thanks, but if i can fix it with css better. a lot of thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".post:nth-of-type(3n)").css("margin-right", "0");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fabricis/7GUwQ/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using jQuery's `filter()` and a modulus on each item's index.

Indexes are 0-based, so I'm adding one to each index.

```
$('.post').filter(function (index) {
    return ((index + 1) % 3 == 0 ? 1 : 0)
}).css('margin-right', '0px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XF5hS/

### EDIT:

For a pure CSS solution, see `nth child` solutions on this page.

Failing that:
If you are generating your divs dynamically, you could just add a class to every third item. If they are not dynamic, you could still just hard-code a class to every third item.

Something like this:

```
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post no-margin"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post no-margin"></div>
```

```
div.post.no-margin {
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: i need add (function($) { code })(jQuery); ?

Comment: Yes, most likely. In the fiddle, I had specified "onDomready" for jQuery. Here's an updated fiddle to reflect "document ready" functionality. http://jsfiddle.net/XF5hS/2/